# Can anyone offer a good reason not to kill the playback tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The concept of playback has a tag at the moment and rather than just re-tag the questions to be about the apps doing the playing, I wanted to see if anyone had a suggestion to not kill this tag.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playback

Comment: Please kill it ASAP!

Comment: I think the silence says it all.

Comment: Ha - [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37194/how-to-resume-normal-iphone-volume-after-notification-causes-volume-to-get-stuck) had both "playback" and "volume" tags. sad trombone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. No one can offer a good reason to spare the tag. Please kill it.

Comment: Done, done and done.